# Undefined when using dynamic variables, not static

Tags: javascript, jquery

MY LOG

```
.main-header 1:939
{"color":"rgb(47, 145, 17)","background-color":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)","font-family":"NeutraText-Book","font-size":"35px"} 1:940
undefined 1:942
[span.custom-color-1.main-header, prevObject: o.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ".main-header", jquery: "2.1.0", constructor: function…]
undefined
```

The loop

```
$.each(currentStyle, function( index, value ) {

    console.log(index);
    console.log(value);

   console.log($("#preview-iframe").contents().find(index).css(value));
   console.log($("#preview-iframe").contents().find('.main-header').css('color', 'blue'));
   console.log($("#preview-iframe").contents().find('.main-header').css({"color":"rgb(47, 145, 17)","background-color":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)","font-family":"NeutraText-Book","font-size":"35px"}));
   console.log($("#preview-iframe").contents().find('.main-header').css(value));

});
```

Basically when I copied the "stuff" from the first two that is logged properly it works, but when I try to use the variables it says undefined.

```
  console.log(index == '.main-header');
```

Says true on the first iteration.

How come? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why does it make no sense trying to find ".main-header"

Comment: What is `currentStyle` exactly?